# Decimal or Float (SQL Server and C++)

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, floating-point, decimal

What is the best way to store 17 decimals (ex. 1.12345678901234567) in a column table in SQL server?

Also which type should I use in C++ to be able to push these 17 decimals into the SQL Query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually seem to have 18 digits there (including the integer part). You would need a 128 bit float to store this, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_precision_floating-point_format (80 bits would work too, if you have access to such a CPU. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision)

To read and store decimal types in C++ you would need to store them as strings. I would look for a GMP math library. (Arbitrary precision math library.)

You will need to give more detail about where the numbers come from to get better advice.

Do you really need exact digits?

Comment: If I debug my code in C++, I can see that my variable (double result) contains 0.1234567890123456.
When I try to insert this into the table I see 0.0000000000000000 instead of the actual value
BTW, I changed the columnt type from float to decimal (16,16)

Answer (score 1):

For your SQL Server column, use [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).
You can specify the percision exactly (17 decimals).